# session destructrion and renewal when session expires

Tags: php, session

I put the data into session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['color']='green';
```

Next time when I receive query the session expires. What will happen? Will old session data be destroyed and new session created with `session_start()`? Will I be able to access data stored from previos requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start()` starts a new session or uses an existing one.

So if the session is not destroyed before `$_SESSION[]` variables will still be there.

`$_SESSION['color']` has the value 'green' until:

- the browser is closed
- the session is unset/destroyed
- the variable is unset

To access `$_SESSION[]` variables there **must** be a `session_start()` at the top of the page, which should access a `$_SESSION[]` variable.

Comment: Thanks, so what you're saying is that session expiration date is not controlled by server? Do you know any good read about PHP sessions?

Comment: Of course there is a limitation of the server configured in the php.ini file. But the time will be reset each time session_start() get's called. You can (for example) take a look [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/) - but there are **many** information about this in the internet.

Comment: Thanks! So until I explicitly destroy session, it will not be destroyed by PHP mechanism, right? (apart from the one configured in php.ini)

Comment: That's correct. But maybe the value in the php.ini get's overwritten with an .htaccess file or ini_set() function. But normally this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen? Will old session data be destroyed and new session
>   created with session_start()?

Until the browser is closed or you implicitly call `session_destroy();` , the session variable will still exist and you can access them on any page.

> Will I be able to access data stored from previos requests?

Yes you can. Just add `session_start();` on the top of your PHP code and you could access it like `echo $_SESSION['color'];`

Answer (score 1):

Session_start() resumes an existing session if one is started before. So your code is just fine

Answer (score 0):

Better you do this :

```
if (session_id() == "") {
  session_start();
}
```

& your value won't be altered after another hit otherwise too